# Gunicorn high memory usage by multiple identical processes?

Tags: python-3.x, web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I am puzzled by the high percentage of memory usage by Gunicorn. The application I am running is a deep learning framework for automatic image recognition.

The memory usage is constantly hovering around 67%, even after I increased the memory size from 1GB to 3GB. What is even puzzling is that the memory seems to be used by multiple identical Gunicorn Processes, as shown below. I have manually killed some high-ram-usage processes such as PID 2004 and 1860, but they constantly came back and the 67% of memory usage remained and sometimes got even higher. As a result, image reading tool such as cv2.imread constantly fails to deal with a large-sized image because of out of memory.

> $ ps aux --sort=-%mem

```
USER  PID  %CPU %MEM VSZ     RSS    TTY    STAT START   TIME COMMAND
user  2004  5.6 39.0 2304052 1201968 ?     S    17:33   0:08 /home/user/anaconda3/envs/project/bin/python /home/user/anaconda3/envs/project/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/user/project-master/project.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
user  1860  2.5 38.6 2289024 1189396 ?     S    17:14   0:32 /home/user/anaconda3/envs/project/bin/python /home/user/anaconda3/envs/project/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/user/project-master/project.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
user  1694  0.0  0.5  43620 17416 ?        Ss   17:14   0:00 /home/user/anaconda3/envs/project/bin/python /home/user/anaconda3/envs/project/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/user/project-master/project.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

I wonder whether it is normal to have such high ram usage for Gunicorn-served web application? If not, is there any way I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Gunicorn pre-forks worker processes, each with a copy of your initialized application inside. Gunicorn _itself_ would not consume a lot. But what does your application do? How does it initialize? Do you have logging around it? Can you run the key part without the web server wrapper? If so, how much RAM does it consume? (You can also configure the number of workers you run.)

Comment: Also, Gunicorn does not release the RAM it allocates to the OS. So if one of your workers has allocated a lot, _it stays allocated_ to the Python process. It may be garbage-collected and usable for following requests, but not for other workers. [See details](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1250#issuecomment-388295335). Try reducing the number of workers, and think about finding the part of code that allocates a huge amount for a short time, and maybe changing the way it operates.

Comment: @9000 Thanks a lot for your comments. I checked my code memory usage on the local computer and found that cv2.imread could take over 1GB ram for a simple image less than 1 MB. I suppose that is the reason why each gunicorn worker needs so much memory? I have downsized the number of workers from 3 to 2. Now the app seems stable with 3GB memory.

Comment: You're welcome, @renjie-ge! I suppose that your images are highly compressed, so 1 MB on disk is with all redundancy removed, while 1 GB in RAM is with every pixel consuming 24 bits (or likely 32 bits). Even so, 1 GB pure RGB pixel data would require a square image with a side of about 18k pixels. I wonder what actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some images once.

Try deleting the variables like that:

```py
del img, otherVar
```